# "Come to justice"

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

The phrase "***bring <somebody>*** *to justice*" is standard English, as confirmed by most major dictionaries.  But the phrase "***come*** *to justice*" cannot be found in most dictionaries, but is definitely on the web.   So, is "***come*** *to justice*" a non-standard variation of "***bring*** *to justice*"?

Answer (score 1):

"Come to justice" is not used, as far as I'm aware.  To bring somebody to justice is to process them through the legal system. If "come to justice" meant anything, it would refer to a criminal submitting themself to the legal system. But we don't use that phrase: we use things like "give oneself up", "turn oneself in" or "surrender to the police".

Comment: Here is just one example: http://www.care2.com/causes/why-the-last-nazis-may-never-come-to-justice.html

Comment: @CocoPop "just one example" suggests that you chose that one from many. When I Googled for "come to justice" with the quotes, all I got was this question and a bunch of false hits from things along the lines of "And then we come to Justice Smith's opinion."

Comment: Ok, here are 1440 examples of "criminals come to justice" https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22criminals+come+to+justice%22

Comment: @CocoPop Except that the 1440 hits that Google reports actually amount to only 23 links. Which overwhelmingly makes my point: "come to justice" is so vanishingly rare that its use can almost be considered a mistake. "Criminals are brought to justice" gives many, many more hits.

Answer (score 0):

"Bring somebody to justice" is used when the authorities actively pursue and prosecute a criminal.

"Come to justice" describes the fate of someone charged with a crime and punished accordingly.

The former is transitive and the latter intransitive.

Comment: So, "come to justice" is non-standard?

Comment: Absolutely not. It is used in situation where someone has seemingly gotten away with a crime, but eventually it catches up to him and he is put through the judicial process to pay for it.

Comment: @meatie "Come to justice" is highly non-standard. Searching for "come to justice" on Google (with quotes) gives few genuine hits (most are of the form "And now we come to Justice So-and-so's opinion") and "criminals come to justice" gives almost none (Google claims 1400+ hits but only actually supplies 23 links).

Comment: It might be an American thing - on all the shows that talk about fugitives, the emphasis is on "making sure that these criminals come to justice."

Comment: @CocoPop ...can you cite that? I have only heard "are brought to justice," but I do not watch a lot of TV. In my American experience, "come to justice" is highly non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Lawbreakers must be brought to juctice.

Lawbbreakers must come to justice.

I think both sentences convey the same sense. The only difference is that the  transitive verb "bring" has been used in the first sentence, whereas the intransitive verb "come" has been used in the second one and that the phrase "bring to justice" is more idiomatic and common, where "come to justice" is rarely used.

Comment: I agree - both of these are quite common in the states. Perhaps David Richerby is only applying a British perspective. I have heard "come to justice" all my life and I'm 52. I heard it again this morning when I watched the movie Olympus Has Fallen: "Be assured that we will not stop until these terrorists come to justice."